# React expand a card on half of screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app and I want a list of small cards on the left of the screen and then when a card is selected, an expanded card shows on the right side of the screen for that selection. I'm not sure what to put for the `onClick`

```
import SplitPane from 'react-split-pane';

export default class Selections extends React.Component {
  showCard(element) {
    var value = element.value;
    document.getElementById(value).style.display = "block";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <SplitPane split="vertical" minSize={300}>
           <div className="card">
             <img src={image_here} />
             <div className="card-body">
               <h5 className="card-title">Item 1</h5>
               <button onClick={showCard} value="item1">See More</button>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div className="card">
             <img src={image_here} />
             <div className="card-body">
               <h5 className="card-title">Item 2</h5>
               <button onClick={showCard} value="item2">See More</button>
             </div>
           </div>
       {/*this div is the right half to show the bigger cards */}
           <div>
              <div className="card">
                <img src={image_here} />
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h5 className="card-title">Item 1 More Info</h5>
                  <p>lorem ipsum....</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="card">
                <img src={image_here} />
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h5 className="card-title">Item 2 More Info</h5>
                  <p>lorem ipsum....</p>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </SplitPane>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

I've attached a demo in CodePen to test the card buttons.

[Card Split Screen](https://codepen.io/deannapi/pen/OJbZNLK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a full answer, but a couple of things that stand out:
I think you mean onClick not onSelect
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Additionally, an event like that would take an event arg, not an element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

I would have put this as a comment but I don't have the rep for it!